# Is this corollary in fact false when $p=1$?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

I'm reading the book "Measure Theory" written by V.I. Bogachev.

In the page 264 we have the following corollary.

> **4.4.5. Corollary.** Let $\mu$ be a nonnegative finite or $\sigma$-finite measure and let $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$, where $1<p<\infty$.
> Suppose that a measurable function $f$ is such that $fg\in L^1(\mu )$
> for all $g\in L^q(\mu )$. Then $f\in L^p(\mu )$.

You can see the proof of this corollary in this [link](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=CoSIe7h5mTsC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA264&dq=measure%20theory%20bogachev&hl=pt-PT&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=measure%20theory%20bogachev&f=false).

This corollary is a consequence of the following proposition.

> **4.4.4. Proposition.** Let $\mu$ be a nonnegative finite and $\sigma$-finite measure on a space $X$. A set $\mathcal{F}$ is bounded
> in $L^p(\mu)$, where $p\in [1,\infty )$, precisely when $\sup _{f\in
> > \mathcal{F}}\int _Xfgd\mu <\infty $ for all $g\in L^{p/(p-1)}(\mu )$.

---

I want to know why the corollary restrict $p\in \color{red}{(}1,\infty )$. I don't see any reason to exclude the case $p=1$ since the proposition that the corollary relies accepts $p=1$.

**My question is:** is that restriction a typo or in fact there's a reason to exclude the case $p=1$?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: If $p=1$, and $1/p+1/q=1$, what is $q$??

Comment: @TonyK $q=\infty$ of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s trivial if $p=1$. Simply take $g=1$ in that case, and your hypothesis implies $fg=f\in L^1$

Answer (score -3):

Consider what $q$ would be in $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$.

Comment: A true simulpost!